# Automating recording fields in a shapefile via pyshp

Tags: python, shapefile, pyshp

I am following the tutorial [here](https://glenbambrick.com/2016/01/09/csv-to-shapefile-with-pyshp/) for how to convert a csv to shp using pyshp. I am almost there, with one issue. In the tutorial, the person loops over the rows in the csv, and for each field, assigns the value of that field to a variable (shortened example):

```
import shapefile # import pyshp library
trees_shp = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POINT)
for row in reader:
   tree_id = row[0]
   address = row[1]
   town = row[2]
   ....
   condition = row[11]
   latitude = row[12]
   longitude = row[13]
```

They then record the new point with attributes like this:

```
trees_shp.point(float(longitude), float(latitude))
trees_shp.record(tree_id, address, town, ..., condition)
```

My question is, is there another (better) way to record field values that are stored in a list (or comma separated string)? i.e. I am looking to record the attributes that are stored in 2 variables (for each row/point):

```
row_str = 'fieldValue1, fieldValue2, fieldValue3'
row_list = ['fieldValue1', 'fieldValue2', 'fieldValue3']
```

I would like to just do something like:

```
outShpWriter = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POINT)
outShpWriter.record(row_str) 
# or
outShpWriter.record(row_list)
```

but each gives me the following error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/shapefile.py", line 1071, in record
    record = [recordList[i] for i in range(fieldCount)]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Is there a workaround besides having to explicitly define variables i.e. (f1 = row_list[0]) and record those variables to the shp?

I ask because the number of fields/fields themselves may change and I would like to automate as much as possible to make it flexible.

Comment: Use [cvs:DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#DictReader) as in [CSV to shapefile missing file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/115398/2581)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`record` method definition in shapefile module:

> ```
> def record(self, *recordList, **recordDict):
>     """Creates a dbf attribute record. You can submit either a sequence of
>     field values or keyword arguments of field names and values. Before
>     adding records you must add fields for the record values using the
>     fields() method. If the record values exceed the number of fields the
>     extra ones won't be added. In the case of using keyword arguments to specify
>     field/value pairs only fields matching the already registered fields
>     will be added."""
> ```

So you can use asteriks '*' for list, and `split` method and asteriks for string in `record` method like that:

```
# *row_list gives 'fieldValue1', 'fieldValue2', ... for a list
outShpWriter.record(*row_list) 

# *row_str.split(',') gives 'fieldValue1', 'fieldValue2', ... for a string
outShpWriter.record(*row_str.split(','))
```

But `fieldValueX` values must be in the same order as field names created for shapefile(.shp).

Or you should use dictionary as @gene states in comments by links.

You probably get the error when you use `row_str`, because a string is iterable object in Python and `record()` method iterates every characters in the string as if each character is a field value. So length of string is more than number of fields, and you get `IndexError: tuple index out of range`.